# Spark Scala - Bitwise operation in filter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a source dataset aggregated with columns col1, and col2.  Col2 values are aggregated by bitwise OR operation. I need to apply filter on the Col2 values to  select records whose bits are on for 8,4,2

initial source raw data

```
val SourceRawData = Seq(("Flag1", 2),
      ("Flag1", 4),("Flag1", 8), ("Flag2", 8), ("Flag2", 16),("Flag2", 32)
      ,("Flag3", 2),("Flag4", 32),
      ("Flag5", 2), ("Flag5", 8)).toDF("col1", "col2")
SourceRawData.show()
+-----+----+
| col1|col2|
+-----+----+
|Flag1|   2|
|Flag1|   4|
|Flag1|   8|
|Flag2|   8|
|Flag2|  16|
|Flag2|  32|
|Flag3|   2|
|Flag4|  32|
|Flag5|   2|
|Flag5|   8|
+-----+----+
```

Aggregated source data based on 'SourceRawData above' after collapsing Col1 values to single row per Col1 value and this is provided other team and Col2 values are aggregated by Bitwise OR operation. Note I here i am providing the output not the actual aggregation logic

```
val AggregatedSourceData = Seq(("Flag1", 14L),
      ("Flag2", 56L),("Flag3", 2L), ("Flag4", 32L), ("Flag5", 10L)).toDF("col1", "col2")

AggregatedSourceData.show()

+-----+----+
| col1|col2|
+-----+----+
|Flag1|  14|
|Flag2|  56|
|Flag3|   2|
|Flag4|  32|
|Flag5|  10|
+-----+----+
```

Now I need to apply filter on the aggregated dataset above to get the rows whose col2  values meeting any of the  (8,4,2) col2 bits are on as per the original source  raw data values

```
expected output
+-----+----+
|Col1 |Col2|
+-----+----+
|Flag1|14  |
|Flag2|56  |
|Flag3|2   |
|Flag5|10  |
+-----+----+
```

I tried something like below and seems to be getting hte expected output but unable to understand how its working.  Is this the correct approach?? if so ,how its working ( I am not that knowledgeable in bitwise operations so looking for expert help to understand please)
`

```
``
var myfilter:Long  = 2 | 4| 8
AggregatedSourceData.filter($"col2".bitwiseAND(myfilter) =!= 0).show()  
 
+-----+----+
| col1|col2|
+-----+----+
|Flag1|  14|
|Flag2|  56|
|Flag3|   2|
|Flag5|  10|
+-----+----+
```

Comment: I have updated the original question, could you please check ?

Comment: `myfilter` is `14` which is binary `1110`. So the `1` bit is clear, the `2`, `4`, `8` bits are set, and no higher order bit is set. The filter will pass any value where any of those three bits is set, which is true for all `Flag` values except for `Flag4`, which has a higher order bit set but none of the three of interest. This is all very basic binary arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to use bitWiseAnd to filter, instead, just use `contains/in` “A set of decimal representation of the bit numbers you want” or `==` to “a decimal representation of a bit number you want”

Also if you try your existing  calculations without Scala or spark, you will see where you understood things wrong, eg use here :

https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/binary-calculator.html

you will find you defined you filter “wrong”.
`18&18` is `18`
`18|2` is `18`

Your dataset the flag column `each row` will only be `one value`, so just filter the flag column , whose values are in the set of numbers you want .

`$"flag == 18` or

`(18,2,20) contains $"flag`  for example

Comment: Thanks for looking. I added sample dataset if that helps and I dont think above approach will work as the values are aggregated using Bitwise OR